# Buildconf not found when compiling php on windows

Tags: windows, php, compile

I am trying to compile PHP on a windows 10 by following below instructions

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2

All steps are ok until I try to perform the buildconf step. In that moment the phpsdk console returns a simple: "'buildconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Is buildconf a part of SDK right? What can it make not to be found? I was expeting it to be reacheable from inside the SDK itself...

I am trying to compile it in a windows 10 VM under Paralells Dekstop (MacOSX) but that should not be a problem right?

Versions used:

- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- PHP 7.3.1
- Windows 10 Professional 64 bit

Any thing that I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably downloaded the binary release.
You need to click "Download source code".
Once you get it in the unpacked format,
you will find `buildconf` at the root of the source folder.

For detailed instructions see
[Build your own PHP on Windows](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2).
Note well the required prerequisites.